# Class casting in java

Tags: java, casting

In my code two classes are there ,subclass extends superclass.In sub class i override superclass method. On the time of object creation i created superclass reference to sub class object its working fine. But again i converted super class reference to complete super class object but it calls sub class methodn not super class method. My assumption the output is wrong.Here my code

```
public class OverRiding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Super class reference to sub class Object
        Dog dog = new Animal();
        dog.eat();
        dog.bow();

        //Completely converted into pure Dog class Object
        Dog d = (Dog) dog;
        d.eat();
        d.bow();
    }
}
```

Dog class

```
class Dog {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Dog eat Biscuits");
    }

    public void bow() {
        System.out.println("Dog bow");
    }
}
```

Class Animal

```
class Animal extends Dog {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Animal eat Food");
    }
}
```

And my output is

```
Animal eat Food
Dog bow
Animal eat Food
Dog bow
```

Comment: Indentation is your best friend.

Comment: `class Animal extends Dog`? hmm I thought vice versa

Comment: And Animal shouldn't extend Dog, because every Animal is not a Dog. It should be the other way: Dog should extend Animal, because a Dog *is an* Animal.

Comment: A cast never changes the type of an object. It only allows getting a reference of a more specific type to an object. An animal will always be an animal, whatever you try to cast it to.

Comment: Casting is NOT conversion!

Answer (score 5):

Your concept is not correct bro...

```
 class Animal extends Dog
```

How can Animal extend a dog? . Its like  saying - "EVERY ANIMAL IS A DOG" . Which is wrong...
So, it should be the other way around...

This example will only confuse you further..

Donno why nobody brought this up...

Answer (score 3):

```
 Dog d = (Dog) dog;
```

Here `d` is not pure `Dog` object. It's still of `Animal` type. Pure `Dog` object would be created via `Dog d = new Dog()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
   Dog dog = new Animal();
    //Completely converted into pure Dog class Object
    Dog d = (Dog) dog;
```

Both `Dog` and `d`  are pointing to the same reference, Since you are not creating a **new** `object`. Cast won't have an effect here.

Casting and Creating is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you've only created one object, and it's an `Animal`, (which sadly, is a special type of `Dog`).  When you call `eat` on this object, you're always going to get the version defined in the `Animal` class, not the version defined in the `Dog` class.

That's polymorphism.  The version of the method that gets called depends on the class of the object, not the type of the variable that refers to it.

Answer (score 1):

You assumption is false:

> Completely converted into pure Dog class Object

When you are casting your `Animal` to a `Dog`, your variable d is still an `Animal`. It is also a `Dog`, but the most specific type is `Animal`.

You are not completely converted your variable to another instance. Your instance is still the same.

For a proof, you can try this code :

```
Dog d = (Dog) dog;
d.getClass(); // output Animal
```